# Why probability cannot be defined on the whole power set?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I'm studying probability. After dealing with discrete probability, my book states that we cannot define such function on an uncountable set, but we need to focus on a subset of it, thus introduces sigma algebras.
But why do we need them in the first place? Why isn't the power set a sigma algebra itself? I cannot see where it does not follow the axioms.
Can you list some examples please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The power set *is* always a sigma algebra - you are right about that.

But sometimes it is not possible to define measures (with certain properties) on the whole power set, and the probability measures defined on the whole power set might be boring or not useful.

A famous theorem which motivates the need for sigma algebra is the following: (note: it is not a probability measure or finite measure)

> There is no measure on $\mu$ defined on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal P(\mathbb R))$ such that
>    (i) $\mu( (a,b) ) = b-a$, (ii) $\mu$ is translation invariant.

See "Vitali Sets" for more information.

There are similar examples for probability measures. 
 One is the infinite coin toss, where again it is not possible to find a probability measure on the whole power set that has the desired properties that one would expect for an infinite coin toss.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why there is no probability measure on the whole power set in the case of infinite coin toss?